# Wait for external script dynamically loaded in AngularJS 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

Because I get my external API key from internal API, I would like to dynamically load external script in my app.js file.

```
import common from './common';

angular.module('app', [common])
  .run(['$rootScope', 'configService', ($rootScope, configService) => {
    $rootScope.googleApiIsReady = false;
    configService.getConfig().then((res) => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      script.setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + res.data.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY + '&libraries=places&language=en-US');
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      $rootScope.googleApiIsReady = true;
    }); 
  }]) 
;
```

The sample of code above works fine (external library loaded in sources) but I don't know how to handle it in controller or directive to wait it is correctly loaded before execute some instructions.

I have a form page with autocomplete input using this API. If I directly refresh this page, the app doesn't have the time to load this external librairy before the autocomplete directive failed to be instanciated. I need to find a way to wait the library to be loaded or to reinstanciate the directive after it is loaded or find a cleaner way to load the lib.

```
module.directive("autoComplete", function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function(scope, elm, $attrs) {
       $rootScope.$watch('googleApiIsReady', function() {
         if ($rootScope.googleApiIsReady) {
           ...
         }
       }, true);  
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: the external api is being loaded in .run(). It should load as soon as the app is loaded therefore i don't think if there is any need for applying wait. are u facing any problem?

Comment: I have completed the question.

Comment: why not add the script in your index.html file

Comment: I could not since I need API key (which I got from a service) in script element url.

Comment: you don't need to generate api key every time. you can just create/setup a new project here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
and get a permanent api key and then use it in index.html

Comment: I know this is possible but this is not what I want to do (it's a constraint that does not depend on me unfortunately).

Comment: then apply timeout on your directive

Comment: I have done something similar, applying a 1 seconde timeout before sending the signal through the $rootScope.googleApiIsReady and it seems to work fine, despite that is more a workaround. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @lakshay, a workaround is to apply a timeout before changing the root scope value.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // Wait 1 sec before active auto completion for the google map libs to be loaded.
  $rootScope.googleApiIsReady = true;
}, 1000);
```